# fetch data from table to Treeview using Oracle DB , asp.net , C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

[exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uioo0.png)I am trying to fetch the forms ID from table to tree view using bellow C# code but it is not working. Form should be displayed according to user privileges

```
    private void treeviewselection()
{

    string xe = "DATA SOURCE=technovalms;USER ID=AMC; password=amc;";

    OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = xe;

    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
    cmd.Connection = conn;

    conn.Open();
    string sms123 = "select G_FROM_ID FROM USER_GROUP ,TECHNOVA_SMS_EMP_MTR,USER_TYPE where USER_TYPE.U_ID=TECHNOVA_SMS_EMP_MTR.SMS_EMP_TYPE and USER_GROUP.G_USER_TYPE=USER_TYPE.U_ID and SMS_USER_ID ='" + Session["SMS_EMP_ID"].ToString() + "'";

    OracleCommand cmd123 = new OracleCommand(sms123, conn);
    cmd123.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    DataSet ds123 = new DataSet();
    OracleDataAdapter dt123 = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd123);
    dt123.Fill(ds123);
    TreeViewtest.DataSource = ds123.Tables[0];
    TreeViewtest.DataBind(); 
}
```

the error:

Additional information: External component has thrown an exception.

Comment: Seems the user account doesn't have the correct permissions.

Comment: When the exception is thrown, open-up the exception details dialog and see the `InnerException`; then post it here.

Comment: in my problem discretion i have added pic of exceptions. please check and let me know why this error